Discrete divergence of a matrix-vector product
This question deals with the divergence of matrix-vector products in the continuous setting. However, I'm looking for an extension to the discrete setting.
Suppose that $\mathbf{A}$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix whose rows / columns (equal due to symmetry) contain the values of a discrete field defined on a three-dimensional grid. Let $\mathbf v$ be an arbitrary $n \times 1$ vector. Can the discrete divergence of $ \mathbf {u} =\mathbf{A} \mathbf{v}$ be written in terms of the discrete divergence of the rows of $\mathbf A$. For example, suppose that the discrete divergence of the rows of $\mathbf A$ are all zero, i.e. $\nabla \cdot \mathbf A_i = 0 \quad \forall i \in [1,n]$, does it follow that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$ for any $\mathbf v$ ? If not, are there any conditions on $\mathbf{A}$ which ensure $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$ ?
In the 1D setting, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf A_i = 0$ implies that each element of $\mathbf{A}_i$ is equal to a constant, $a$, and by symmetry, all rows are also equal to the same constant. $\mathbf{u}$ is therefore also constant as each entry is equal to $a \sum_{i=1}^n v_i$. I'm hoping there is a similar extension to the 3D setting.

Yes, you can. But to compute discrete divergence you need the incidence matrix associated with edges defined on this grid, which defines the positive directions of the grid so that you can measure the flux:
$$
    g_{ik} = \begin{cases}
    -1 & \text{if $v_i\in \mathcal{V}$ if $e_k = \vec{v_i v_{j}} \in \mathcal{E}$}\\
    +1 & \text{if $v_i\in \mathcal{V}$ if $e_k = \vec{v_j v_{i}} \in \mathcal{E}$}\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$
Suppose your vector field array is associated with edges in that $\mathbf{u} := [\mathbf{u}_k]_{k=1}^{N_{\mathcal{E}}} \in \mathbb{R}^{N_{\mathcal{E}}\times 3}$, then the discrete divergence is
$$
\sum_{\text{three components row-wise}}\left(\underset{e_k\in \mathcal{E} \text{ has vertex } v_i }{\sum} g_{ik}\mathbf{u}_k \right)
$$
which will be a $\mathbb{R}^{N_\mathcal{V} \times 1}$ array. In computation, $G = (g_{ik})$ should be an $N_\mathcal{V}\times N_\mathcal{E}$ matrix, and multiply it with your $N_\mathcal{E}
\times 3$ yields the discrete divergence.

Thank you for your answer. I don't fully understand your notation, do you mind explaining each of the terms you introduce?
Also do you mind showing how to go from $\nabla \cdot \mathbf A_i = 0 \quad \forall i \in [1,n]$ to  $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$

@AnthonyPadua In your notation, if there is an $n\times n$ grid, $\mathbf{u}(x_{ij}) = \mathbf{A}{ij}$, then $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n \times 2}$, and correspondingly $N{\mathcal{V}} = n^2$ is the number of vertices. In my notation $\mathbf{u}$ is your $\mathbf{A}$ flattened. You need to know the topology of your grid to compute divergence (how the grid points are connected).

I think there is a slight misunderstanding. $\mathbf{u}$ is not equal to $\mathbf{A}$ but to the matrix-vector product of $\mathbf{A}$ with an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{v}$. $\mathbf{v}$, and each of the rows of $\mathbf{A}$ are defined on the same grid as $\mathbf{u}$. What I'm asking is: is it sufficient that if each row of $\mathbf{A}$ is discrete divergence free, the product $\mathbf u = \mathbf A \mathbf v$ is also discrete divergence free?
